# The meaning of this syntax

Tags: pointers, constants

Could you pleas describe me what is the meaning of :

> const char* const*

Comment: Looks like a syntax error. What does it do?

Comment: I don't know it was given by the lecturer

Comment: I put in http://cdecl.org and it said it was a syntax error.

Comment: @ratbum It's not when you add an identifier to it. [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=const+char*+const*+p)

Comment: @Rawhi: did you at least try deciphering it by yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this makes the inner pointer readonly (const):

while this will compile:

```
char *foo = NULL;
const char** bar = NULL;
bar[0] = foo;
```

this wont:

```
char *foo = NULL;
const char* const* bar = NULL;
bar[0] = foo;
```

as setting the inner pointer is not allowed.